# How to slice a pandas.DataFrame?

Tags: pandas

Here's a pd.Dataframe.

```
index date  state
one   2000  Ohio
two   2012  Ohio
```

And I want `df['state'] = 'California' where df['date'] == 2000 and df.index == one`.

How can I do this?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html

Comment: df.loc[(df.state == 'California' ) & (df.date == 2000) & (df.index == 'one')]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use if `index` is not column set new values by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with conditions:

```
print (df.columns)
Index(['date', 'state'], dtype='object')

df.loc[(df['date'] == 2000) & (df.index == 'one'), 'state'] = 'California'
print (df)
       date       state
index                  
one    2000  California
two    2012        Ohio
```

If index is column select it by `[]`:

```
print (df.columns)
Index(['index', 'date', 'state'], dtype='object')

df.loc[(df['date'] == 2000) & (df['index'] == 'one'), 'state'] = 'California'
print (df)
  index  date       state
0   one  2000  California
1   two  2012        Ohio
```

Comment: It really helps! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
df.loc[df.state=='California' and df.date==2000 and df.index=='one', :]
```